# phpBB and Moodle Integration

Tags: php, moodle, phpbb

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a phpBB and moodle integration?

I would like to use the phpBB user information for moodle so a user has to just sign on with their normal username and password for my phpBB forum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how phpBB handles the password hashing nowadays, but maybe you can use external database authentication for it, see https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/External_database_authentication

Should work with MD5 and SHA-1 at least

Comment: I was doing some looking about and found that they use PHPass for password hashing :(

Comment: You can of course achieve your goal with an authentication plugin, but this might involve some coding and moodle knowledge. Quick&Dirty solution would be modifying phpBB so that user registration also saves SHA-1 hashed password in an additional row/table. And then connect the way described above. As mentioned, really a bit hacky, quick&dirty

Comment: Do you know how to do that? php and  MySQL noob here

Comment: I could figure it out, if i would have time time. But unfortunately not...

Comment: Ah, ok thanks for your help though. I did see this, [document](http://www.phpbbhacks.com/forums/phpbb3-password-hashing-vt73283.html) do you think it could work?

Comment: Hi Harry, please check the following gist. You could replace the functions phpbb_hash and phpbb_check_hash, i think located in includes/functions_compatibility.php. If you replace those 2 functions, passwords should be saved as SHA1 hash (i did not test it with phpbb, so I cannot assure if it really works). Please note, that it will only work with a plain phpbb installation, otherwise existing users, also admin, would not be able to login. So replace the functions first, then install phpbb. https://gist.github.com/Sebastiansch/73a2bc41b85810555279ee5baad20c33